# error entering data int SQL DB

Tags: django-models

This should be a easy one.  I am getting an error that I don't understand.  I think I need to prefill the DB with null values to fix this but I am unclear if that is the case.  I am getting the following error which I don't understand the meaning of...

Cannot add "": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"

the models.py has the following definitions...

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = "20", primary_key = True)

class Page(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length="45", primary_key = True) 
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

the view that is failing to render is ...

```
def save_page(request, page_name):
    date =  datetime.date.today()
    content = request.POST["content"]
    tag_list = []
    if "tags" in request.POST:
        tags = request.POST["tags"]
        tag_list = [Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0] for tag in tags.split()]

    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        page.content = content
        for tag in tag_list:
            page.tags.add(tag)

    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        page = Page(name=page_name, content = content, pub_date = date)
        for tag in tag_list:
            page.tags.add(tag)

    page.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/page/" + page_name +"/")
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/wikicamp/page/Start/save/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wikicamp.wiki',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\web dev\training\Django\secondproj\wikicamp\..\wikicamp\wiki\views.py" in save_page
  80.           page.tags.add(tag)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in add
  503.                 self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in _add_items
  563.                                                (obj, self.instance._state.db, obj._state.db))

Exception Type: ValueError at /wikicamp/page/Start/save/
Exception Value: Cannot add "<Tag: Tag object>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"
```

Comment: Are you asking for the Traceback information?  I will add anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a [router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)?  I think your router setup is mis-configured.  It looks like Django thinks the Page instance and the Tag instance you are adding to it are not associated with the same database source. This is something that would get set up in a router.

Comment: No I am debugging a training program on the same system.  I am using the free webserver from Django found in the official tutorial 1 using manage.py and testing from a browser on the same computer.  My computer is connected to a router to access the internet but I have had no issues with it.  Let me turn off the router and see if it still works but I think it shouldn't matter...

Comment: I don't mean a network router, rather a django router (the link I included in the answer explains what it is).

Comment: ya know I just killed it and restarted and it appears to not throw the error but I don't think it is saving the data into the data base.  I will read that section you point to and see if that helps.  Thanks